# Use of break and continue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know with core Javascript we can do things like this:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++){
   if(i==5){
    //break or continue
   }
}
```

But why this is not correct ?

```
$.each(iteratorarray,function(i){ //iteratorarray - just an array
  if(i==5){
    //break or continue,will cause error here
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)?

Comment: That's just as core javascript as the first one, it's a normal function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This *behavior is what is implemented by jQuery*. This is what jQuery api document say "We can `break` the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`. Returning `non-false` is the same as a `continue` statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration", You can read about it [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 4):

`return` will continue, `return false` will break.  The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) talks about the `break` substitute by example, but it still specifies the functionality of `return` in the `.each` callback.

Answer (score 2):

> why this is not correct?

[`break`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.7) or [`continue`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.8) statements are only valid as a part of a (for-, for-in-, while-, …) [loop statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6). You cannot do that in a plain function. From the spec:

> A program is considered syntactically incorrect if […]
>   the program contains a continue/break statement […] directly or indirectly (**but not crossing function boundaries**), within an `IterationStatement`.

Instead, you can `return` from a function (which breaks further execution of the function body). As you can read in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), returning `false` stops the iteration in `$.each`.

Comment: break can be implemented by `return false` what about `continue`

Comment: Just `return` premature from the function body.

Answer (score 2):

`$.each` uses a callback to execute the custom code, `break` is a control statement which can disrupt the wrapping loop. The `break` or `continue` has to be call directly from the `loop` body not from a delegated function.

```
$.each(iteratorarray,function(i){ //iteratorarray - just an array
  if(i==5){
    //break or continue,will cause error here
  }
});
```

Can be considered as equals to

```
for(i=0;i<iteratorarray.length;i++){
    if(callback(i, iteratorarray[i]) === false){
        break;
    }
}
```

Here your code is residing inside the `callback()` function therefore you cannot use `loop control` statements inside the callback.

You can read more in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 1):

In the `$.each` case, there is no loop you can break out of, and that's why you get the error.  The way jQuery does it, however, is that the loop `breaks` if your function returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JavaScript's [every](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679981%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method for iterating array elements.

> The every method calls the callbackfn function one time for each array
>   element, in ascending index order, until the callbackfn function
>   returns false. If an element that causes callbackfn to return false is
>   found, the every method immediately returns false. Otherwise, the
>   every method returns true.